# Отнять число с условием и получением результата

Tags: c#, sql

Мне нужно отнять одно число от другого, если первое число больше или равно второму, при этом получить ответ, команда выполнена успешно (число отнялось) или нет.

Сейчас метод выглядит так:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"UPDATE Users 
                                        SET Coins = CASE 
                                            WHEN Coins >= @num THEN Coins - @num
                                            ELSE Coins
                                            END
                                        WHERE Id = @id", sqlConnection);



    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", 10);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", 123);

    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Как мнне получить ответ, было вычитание из числа, или нет?

Comment: я не спец, но 3 секунды поисков посоветовали глядеть в сторону `@@ROWCOUNT`, если у вас MSSQL

Comment: Укажите ТОЧНО Вашу СУБД, включая версию.

Comment: В любом случае - нужно в структуру таблицы добавить соответствующий CHECK constraint и не валять дурака со всякими проверками. Ограничение просто не позволит выполнить операцию, если конечное состояние не соответствует наложенному ограничению.

Comment: @Akina Microsoft SQL Server 13.00.4001, добавленный через студию. Можете на моём примере показать, как правильно использовать CHECK constraint и получать статус выполнено - не выполнено? У SqlCommand я не нашёл в параметрах что-то похожее на статус

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT Coins_Not_Negative CHECK (Coins >= 0);`. Если конечное состояние не соответствует ограничению, запрос завершится с ошибкой, которую следует отловить в программе, а данные не будут изменены.

Comment: @Akina сделал немного иначе, через параметры создания таблицы `[Coins] MONEY NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 Check([Coins] >= 0),`. Спасибо за решение, можете оформить как ответ

Comment: Ну это неважно, ограничение столбца или таблицы. Эффект тот же. Просто в комменте ограничение столбца написать проще.